# Psycopg2 is passing parameters to SQL queries - Is anyone able to tell me what is wrong with this sql statement?

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I get the following error:

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError

psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "%"
LINE 1: ... pt, gss.shapes g WHERE st_contains(geom,pos) AND %(postcode...
                                                             ^
```

When I run the following on pgAdmin:

```
Select DISTINCT gss, description, postcode 
FROM postcodelatlng pt, gss.shapes g 
WHERE st_contains(geom,pos) 
AND %(postcode)s~* '(\y(?:[A-PR-UWYZ](?:[A-HK-Y]?\d{1,2}|\d[A-HJKMNP-Y]|[A-HK-Y]\d[ABEHMNPRV-Y]))(?:\s*\d[ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2})\y)' limit 50
```

Comment: `%(postcode)s` is not a valid identifier in SQL do you really have a column with that name?

Comment: `%(postcode)s` is named parameter for `psycopg2` to use to supply a parameter value. You have two issues 1) You have not supplied a value to be substituted for the parameter 2) Even if you did it would not work as parameters cannot be used for identifier names

Comment: Should have added  issue: 3) The pgAdmin query tool does not have method for supplying parameters.

Comment: Hi, thanks, the postcode is a column within a table all I would like to do is be able to supply any postcode by getting a prompt then to input the postcode which will then get rendered by a html page. However I get the following error still: psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError

psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "%"
LINE 1: ... pt, gss.shapes g WHERE st_contains(geom,pos) AND %(postcode...
                                                             ^

Comment: he main SQL code is as follow:

Select DISTINCT gss, description, postcode FROM postcodelatlng pt, gss.shapes g WHERE st_contains(geom,pos) AND %(user_input)s~* '(\y(?:A-PR-UWYZ)(?:\s*\d[ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2})\y)' limit 50

But I still get the same error:

ERROR: syntax error at or near "%" LINE 7: AND %(user_input)s~* '(\y(?:[A-PR-UWYZ](?:[A-HK-Y]?\d{1,2}|... ^ SQL state: 42601 Character: 124

Comment: Are you running this in the Query Tool in `pgAdmin`? If so parameter substitution will not work period. If you are not using `pgAdmin` then tell us where you are running this? FYI, add updates to your question section not as comments.

Comment: The main code is the following below somethong is wrong:

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not using the correct syntax for [passing parameters in psycopg2](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries). The correct syntax (in Python) is something like

```
cur.execute("SELECT * from mytable WHERE mycolumn = %s", (myvalue,))
```

OR

```
cur.execute("""SELECT * from mytable 
              WHERE mycolumn = %(data)s""", {'data':myvalue})
```

The second one is called %(name)s placeholder. `name` has to be a dictionary key, not a variable. So I think your code has to become something like

```
postcodevar = input('Please enter postcode: ')
cur.execute("""SELECT DISTINCT gss, description, postcode 
                 FROM postcodelatlng pt, gss.shapes g 
                WHERE st_contains(geom,pos) 
                  AND %(postcode)s~* '(\y(?:[A-PR-UWYZ](?:[A-HK-]?\d{1,2}|d[A-HJKMNP-Y]|[A-HK-Y]\d[ABEHMNPRV-Y]))(?:\s*\d[ABD-HJLNP-UW-]{2})\y)' 
                LIMIT 50""", {'postcode': postcodevar})
```

Comment: This is an incorrect answer. First @user3873614 says they are doing this in `pgAdmin` which means none of the answer will work. I suspect they may actually being doing this elsewhere. In any case your last example will not work as a parameter can not be used to specify an identifier, in this case a column name.

Comment: User is essentially running the query in BOTH Python/Psycopg2 AND pgAdmin. The query will not work unmodified in pgAdmin. My last example should work as it follows the syntax in the documentation link. The named argument `postcode` is replaced by the contents of the Python variable `postcodevar`. Neither of these are column names. The column name is `postcodelatlong`. Everything after `AND` is a little unusual because there is no column name, but it should work and is an unusual way of doing error checking. The error checking would be better done before the query.

Comment: Ah, I see now how that would work. Yes, unusual.

Comment: When I test such sql I get the following: TypeError

TypeError: argument 1 must be a string or unicode object: got tuple instead